# Typescript: How To Use Generics Properly To Infer Return Type of Function Correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've the following types

```js
type ItemDefaultType = object | null | string

interface ItemToString<Item = ItemDefaultType> {
  (item: ItemDefaultType): string;
}

interface AutosuggestState<Item = ItemDefaultType> {
  highlightedIndex: number | null
  inputValue: string | null
  isOpen: boolean
  selectedItem: Item
}

interface AutosuggestProps<Item = ItemDefaultType> extends AutosuggestState<Item> {
  itemToString?: ItemToString<Item>;

  initialSelectedItem?: Item;
  initialInputValue?: string;
  initialHighlightedIndex?: number | null;
  initialIsOpen?: boolean;

  defaultHighlightedIndex?: number | null;
  defaultIsOpen?: boolean;

  id?: string;
  inputId?: string;
  labelId?: string;
  menuId?: string;

  itemCount?: number
}
```

I want to make a `getInitialValue` function with the intended signature –

```
// this has to be done correctly using generics, not been able to do it, read on…
(
  props: Props extends AutosuggestProps,
  stateKey: StateKey extends keyof AutosuggestState
) => AutosuggestState[StateKey] // return the correct type of AutosuggestState property based on which stateKey was passed
```

The behaviour of `getInitialValue` looks like this

```js
// javascript version

const defaultStateValues = {
  highlightedIndex: -1,
  isOpen: false,
  selectedItem: null,
  inputValue: ''
}

function getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey) {
  const defaultPropKey = `default${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (defaultPropKey in props) {
    return props[defaultPropKey]
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue(props, statePropKey) {
  if (statePropKey in props) {
    return props[statePropKey]
  }
  const initialPropKey = `initial${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (initialPropKey in props) {
    return props[initialPropKey]
  }
  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}
```

I'm finding it hard to write types of both `getInitialValue` and `getDefaultValue` such that `getInitialValue` correctly infers the right type as below –

```js
const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem') // selectedItem variable should correctly be inferred as **object | null | string** since that's what its type is in **AutosuggestState** interface
```

Can someone help me write the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible typing, which might or might not fit your use case:

```
function getDefaultValue<P extends AutosuggestProps, K extends keyof AutosuggestState>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K) {
  const defaultPropKey = `default${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (defaultPropKey in props) {
    return props[defaultPropKey as K] // assert here
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue<P extends AutosuggestProps, K extends keyof AutosuggestState>(
  props: P, statePropKey: K) {
  if (statePropKey in props) {
    return props[statePropKey]
  }
  const initialPropKey = `initial${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (initialPropKey in props) {
    return props[initialPropKey as K] // assert here
  }
  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}
```

All I've really done is make the functions generic in `P` and `K` of the types you alluded to in your pseudocode.

One decision you need to make is what to do when you use `defaultPropKey` and `initialPropKey`.  The compiler has no way to verify that prepending  `"default"` or `"initial"` to a property name will, if it exists, pick out another property of the same type.  The compiler does not understand string concatenation at the type level (the suggestion for doing so in Github seems to be [microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)).  If you could refactor your interfaces so that the default and initial values are stored in properties named `default` and `initial` which are themselves objects holding properties of the *same* keys, then you could make the compiler figure it out.  Assuming that you're keeping it this way, I've used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to say, for example, "treat `initialPropKey` *as if it were* of type `K`".  Then the compiler will assume that `props[initialPropKey]` is of the same type as `props[statePropKey]`.

Anyway, now the return types of those functions are inferred as

```
P[K] | {
    highlightedIndex: number;
    isOpen: boolean;
    selectedItem: null;
    inputValue: string;
}[K]
```

which makes sense since it uses `defaultStateValues` at the end, which is a concrete type not known to be the extended `P` type.  This might be tightened up by using a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) return type, but your example code didn't show a need for that.

Let's see if it works:

```
declare const props: AutosuggestProps;
const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem');
// const selectedItem: ItemDefaultType
```

Looks reasonable to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=65&ssc=1&pln=68&pc=1#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-CnFQzxzEGKsa3oetcGY1iQGyAADfjgAAEjMK8bwRapH2fIRrG4JiaKEzwghExYiOscTBPwikoGopDOPbKwoCPYBMB4ZgjJozgAG09LUgz0EhVCAF1BhCclLOs2zxPI0DHJU+B9JALzRB8sRf3-WzAMaUVQPUcDIIhYi4Lhd57JQ9C0uwvCCKI2Dniy8jjEo8ljNoqB6MYsKXJAdjTO0mxQogcLDOqzgWvJKw-JsuykIc9rwsiqwfKsHja3VTVOpIETZomKSZNveSn0JZSEQar51M01rbEpDUJk6gQhu+XrzIsiArMG7qHKW7BOrctDxqgSbrtu+KbuAnl1wgaxupQ0bGs8XdRH3Q9oGm+huqcErSIQ+zSRhrg6ROM4-hIBKjs1UDAZyqBN1nekbXsTdPFJAB6KnL2rWsSYxrQ8VyQF8kIa4gA)

Comment: Thank you jcalz, for responding so quickly! I really appreciate it. When one is learning something new, with a wide expanse of unknown, not knowing things gets intimidating quickly

I got what I was doing wrong. I wasn't type asserting <key> as K, but was trying to type assert the return value itself, which doesn't make any sense.

Could you, if you can, also extend your explanation with the tightening of the return type of 'getInitialValue' with conditional return type as well? It'd help learn.

Comment: If I look at this more closely I find I'm confused... `AutosuggestProps` extends `AutosuggestState`, meaning all the properties in the latter are also in the former and none are `undefined`.  So `getInitialValue<P extends AutosuggestProps, K extends keyof AutosuggestState>(p: P, k: K)` is essentially guaranteed to return a value of type `P[K]`, no conditional type needed.  But then the check `statePropKey in props` is guaranteed to be `true` so there's no point implementing the rest of it.  So perhaps your interfaces or types are off and you should triple-check them.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I'm sorry, I don't know how I missed this. `AutosuggestProps` should be

`interface AutosuggestProps<Item = ItemDefaultType> extends Partial<AutosuggestState<Item>>{…}` i.e. all `AutosuggestState` keys should be optional in `AutosuggestProps`. How to go about the problem now? How can we ensure that return type is correct now?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't necessarily commit to keep coming back to look at this, since I've already spent a considerable amount of time here.  If you can't figure it out yourself and need eyes on it you might want to open a new question with the new type definitions so that you're not sitting around waiting for me specifically.

Comment: I understand that. If my request doesn't sound very insisting, could you please take a look at it? The above mentioned change in one type is the only change needed for the question to be correct. It wouldn't take you more than one more glance. A little bit of your time, could save me many minutes. I haven't been able to figure it out. I'll update both the question and your answer if and when you answer.

Comment: I don't get it; my original answer still works, but it includes `undefined` because the value `{selectedItem: undefined}` is now a possible input. If you want a more targeted conditional type based function signature that itself tries to narrow down to the particular output based on the input, that's more than a few additional minutes of my time. If there's something you still can't figure out, I need more specific information about what the issue is, and I still suggest a new question, since this one is answered as asked, and I can't guarantee my continued involvement here.

Comment: Asked — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705634/get-a-more-targeted-conditional-type-based-function-signature-that-tries-to-narr