# Get a more targeted conditional type based function signature that tries to narrow down to the particular output based on the input

Tags: typescript, types

I've the following types

```js
type ItemDefaultType = object | null | string

interface ItemToString<Item = ItemDefaultType> {
  (item: Item): string;
}

interface AutosuggestState<Item = ItemDefaultType> {
  highlightedIndex: number | null
  inputValue: string | null
  isOpen: boolean
  selectedItem: Item
}

interface AutosuggestProps<Item = ItemDefaultType>
  extends Partial<AutosuggestState<Item>> {
    itemToString?: ItemToString<Item>;

    initialSelectedItem?: Item;
    initialInputValue?: string | null;
    initialHighlightedIndex?: number | null;
    initialIsOpen?: boolean;

    defaultHighlightedIndex?: number | null;
    defaultIsOpen?: boolean;
}
```

I have the following typed code

```js
function capitalizeString(string: string) {
  return `${string.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${string.slice(1)}`
}

const defaultStateValues: AutosuggestState<null> = {
  highlightedIndex: -1,
  isOpen: false,
  selectedItem: null,
  inputValue: ''
}

function getDefaultValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {
  const defaultPropKey = `default${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (defaultPropKey in props) {
    return props[defaultPropKey as K] // assert here
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {
  if (statePropKey in props) {
    return props[statePropKey]
  }
  const initialPropKey = `initial${capitalizeString(statePropKey)}`
  if (initialPropKey in props) {
    return props[initialPropKey as K] // assert here
  }
  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}
```

On doing

```js
declare const props: AutosuggestProps;
const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem');
```

`selectedItem` shows the return type `object | null | string | undefined`. But by the nature of the `getInitialValue` and `getDefaultValue` functions, it is sure that at least the default value for `selectedItem` will be returned from the `defaultStateValues` object.

1. How to write more targeted conditional type based function signature for `getInitialValue` and `getDefaultValue` that tries to narrow down to the particular output based on the input i.e. `selectedItem` has type `ItemDefaultType` instead of `object | null | string | undefined` ( which is really `ItemDefaultType | undefined` )
2. Is there a better way to write the types and the functions? For example, in this question —

[Typescript: How To Use Generics Properly To Infer Return Type of Function Correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643699/typescript-how-to-use-generics-properly-to-infer-return-type-of-function-correc/58646552?noredirect=1#comment103697346_58646552)

The answerer has suggested that the type assertions might not be needed —

> If you could refactor your interfaces so that the default and initial values are stored in properties named **default** and **initial** which are themselves objects holding properties of the same keys, then you could make the compiler figure it out

Are there other structural changes to the type definitions and interfaces that could be done?

**Note**: if you only have time to answer one, answer the 1st one please.

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-prFhBmDq1hsttT-DTUJhmHQ+KRmFAaOgwHYRnwAF4QMlqawKoQTckucy9HgQYCYHipgAGABIzMXBAA6TjlWTWAAMABooABGFxtyIAVTAkB4AGF0LtrC5fM3Wx2uxBrMPfPWzjSaCnuPbfoZEvAZWNOE44fdEcAT6j-aYSPkimyKpy6o0nABaQd92ZasMnAwbBdj-Wldn2S1EGaNgwKNKUz3GKAAHJkJ3MR40TKEUygOJgEyQxEPUXonigIEwyqUErwRR4XjeTg4KgABpMiGmBSioAAawgEBSFQG4InhB4kRRMRjGsXowFed4nCeRjuBROiwCYninCYsRy2fNN93oINDCUlSQDSes9NwZt00zZFyjzAshCLZF4AMnjF23Wk+H46xTOeaTDPpKApPozS7SrGs6386TOAAbS8pyjLnZiAF0oAAemSqA512SEoEKdoIF6WMrBC2tUy8u9EKihTHJ8niEvQ0RMKTHC8NqdUiJI1j2KowTr1oiLGJY8iQS4ni+IEu4aJE+AxIk2kApksF5IciBYrUjSKzcjzKuW6qjIEcLAvW0UirCuaKqW2LatpArtOYA81RNbBYuM+6mXMjMs2s-N8XsxSdpc2YPJekYnr206gtpQrq2K-b3kioHHp29LQSYpLUqRzL6Byqt8srKGwrwgjcEQ6xToHLbYpcOr6hobAIWgPdbvoU7L26ibvPo6kGYPCCLXdVISGa40mWJ0mUJ5g4jkQZCXC8IA) with code pre written in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt at dealing with this would be to do the structural refactoring mentioned and use the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) utility type to represent the constraint that `undefined` is not a possible output when you guard against `undefined` values.

So the refactoring looks like this:

```
interface AutosuggestProps<Item = ItemDefaultType>
  extends Partial<AutosuggestState<Item>> {
  itemToString?: ItemToString<Item>;

  initial?: {
    highlightedIndex?: number | null;
    inputValue?: string | null;
    isOpen?: boolean;
    selectedItem?: Item;
  }

  default?: {
    highlightedIndex?: number | null;
    inputValue?: string | null;
    isOpen?: boolean;
    selectedItem?: Item;
  }

}
```

And the functions look like this:

```
function getDefaultValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {
  if (props.default && typeof props.default[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    const ret = props.default[statePropKey]
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>;
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {
  if (statePropKey in props && typeof props[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    const ret = props[statePropKey];
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>;
  }
  if (props.initial && typeof props.initial[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    const ret = props.initial[statePropKey];
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>;
  }
  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}
```

That gives the following result:

```
declare const props: AutosuggestProps;
const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem');
// const selectedItem: ItemDefaultType
```

Maybe that's enough for you.

---

If you need a conditional type signature that tries to anticipate which branch will actually happen in each function and output a tighter type, this will come at the expense of less type safety inside the implementation of the functions, since the compiler doesn't perform this analysis automatically, nor can it verify that the manual conditional type will actually match what comes out of the function.

Anyway, it might look like this:

```
type IdxWithDefault<T, K extends keyof any, D = never> = T extends any ? K extends keyof T ?
  Exclude<T[K], undefined> | (undefined extends T[K] ? D : never) : D : never
```

The type `IdxWithDefault<T, K, D>` tries to look up the key `K` in the type `T`.  If that succeeds and the property is not `undefined`, it evaluates to `T[K]`.  Otherwise, it evaluates to `D`.  And it distributes over unions, so if `T[K]` is `string | undefined`, then the output will be `string | D`.

Now the function signatures can use `IdxWithDefault`:

```
function getDefaultValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
): IdxWithDefault<
  P["default"], K, IdxWithDefault<
    typeof defaultStateValues, K
  >
>
function getDefaultValue(props: AutosuggestProps, statePropKey: keyof AutosuggestState) {
  if (props.default && typeof props.default[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    return props.default[statePropKey]
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue<
  P extends AutosuggestProps,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
): IdxWithDefault<
  P, K, IdxWithDefault<
    P["initial"], K, IdxWithDefault<
      P["default"], K, IdxWithDefault<
        typeof defaultStateValues, K>
    >
  >
>;
function getInitialValue(props: AutosuggestProps, statePropKey: keyof AutosuggestState) {
  if (statePropKey in props && typeof props[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    return props[statePropKey];
  }
  if (props.initial && typeof props.initial[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    return props.initial[statePropKey];
  }
  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}
```

Testing it... this is the same, since `props` is only known to be `AutosuggestProps`.

```
declare const props: AutosuggestProps;
const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem');
```

But the following outputs the `string` type:

```
getInitialValue({
  selectedItem: "wheee"
}, "selectedItem"); // string
```

This is about as far as I can go here, I think.  If you discover edge cases that don't behave as you expect, you can play around with the nested `IdxWithDefault` types.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAiEBmBDArgG2AFXGgF4oB7AIwCsIBjYKAHygDsdtGoBnYAJwEtmAcwCwAKDED4PDDWhxEeUgGVeAwQB55CKCS0oMOfIQB8UAN5ioUABR94CAFyx7ASifd+QgNxiAvmIlmKRloAEFMYFJOTEFBCG4VdHhNex1nRH0sXAJIUwtRKwALPkFC7BLC+AATGGYqiAAPJ1YEcggeDlZsbEsoATAIgDV0bEwId1UhTrZevk4AeUhmJ3JSUmwIdGZezggNugga+yctPwDRSXaQqHDI6Nj44AAFHlIwThTENL00LKNc3qNeB1ThQJ7oHjAPgjdS3KIxOIJYBJCCfBDGPKzeyKFSeQQAfhO2OUkw0WmMPnEBT6zDs0OwhPMvSKFXKpWqtXqDUZLTaHSYXWwlKsVn6QxGY0ZHjU026wpFc0WEGYjNW602zHlVl2+w59kZWnl-ipVnqBlwjPyIqgxVKbMqh05jR5mFa7VlQuZNIGwGGowgUtJHq1fQWS1Vaw2WxDOtoesQBvsRvOxrENFIzG4UDNf0S8D9Y04Tjh90RwDzqMFphIVptrIqHLqjScAFoAIwAGlmYeVTgw2F2XepsYOR0QzTYQ9FzB9BfGUAA5AuzlSxMx0Ah4mB0LIoAAxPg8bihYD2MD0fK9VCYZh0PgZqBxYCZQxz9Rep5QIHKqqgksIx4XjeTgpxFABpL8GmBX8oAAawgEBSFQG4InhB4kRRXpjGsL0wFed4nCeUDtWReAgLAMCEKcMDehcJlqVFZDrDw4CADoc0MKAADIuKgUBICQqAWPedjfkMABtbgUXIyiQAAXSgABCIgSAAIhvM0BEOVS6Nra100zegeAgegSGEzhRPNYBJNIiAZIQuSvSsYzgEwHhmCgFyoHQUEAFEGhoUZ6nUfiIEElyOygDS0C0qoKS9Y1rRctyPI43AKznTgbOk-DZMc6lU2pa9byhB8n1qOkRjfD9IOgv9UNLQD8JAr0IO-EE4IQwT-3Q8tbKwnCGKE5rCOIrhbPskBqNo+jrT4JipLI3KEJpYbgO43jQsE8zsqWt48qUlSoHUptUFinTZutKADKzLyzOa3a7OW+SQ2ckyUs8kzvL8gKgtRLbkIiqLTti+KhsShUmPM1iBEq9geL4whtuamHaShEZHsmhTlLU6KzuYbTdKc66M1ur77rY2H0ewTHnrk17Ptc9zGe+qB-MCzBgoBxnIrx0GQwht6mY8p8X1wOdmOayLFqe-aEJcXpCtNWhsAhaAbvocziwagDuHIzh5Q1rg9jjR1UhIcq0fpCXzMihcR3jBAFxcSlektuGJb043dTN8djoAd0KCBg9UxXItUh3fYQHSvCgAB6OP0mQMTskIKByAiKAEAbKB-a2ehpSEfEU3OddN04bddwAYQzKo6QzEYcmgWtQtgKoGgAdTsQoxeAdQ8EitqoJ-UF4MQ5CthASKkDSAmADd2mrKA8FqkfvOYEAoHxKAh7qzrx+XrevXZv7+-EsC5N5kGCbijhrD5m-V46vBz4U7eZ+aCAF54OinA-lgv7tHOFYYqd4yomV7tVIan52owR6mWfWY1d5rzHt1HWvUKwDVwiNMEY0ZaTWmtSNwbdO7d17u+aB4lVJpWAKpS+O9IowHbl3YAPcU592JtzGhGUJTxEHl6YwWErw3jASLCB7CbY4PgU1YC0sJrPScKg5C0iMLwCJkNeaNhoY0I2ojASyFtHsNpnLeSh1cbX0JpdJK71maGKssYiiDkEpemSszbhtlMoOLyorYBUBQGlTEcACq1MoHWhgcPDqKjnhS1ak-GCSiUJ3F1n1TC1JsLYOAqNL0+CFE71oicZhZD2EULCYPRhhTWHkOJk8KhVN6R0LKSQlhbCrIlKulYGp1D2ENIYU0oprTibWi4ewnh-oQI70EUNKwkzrQzKgGDEBIiAmPhMsE62vDJaZMSWhBBUtxo5RMYorqyj0FlgrOouaC15EmNWuZXR3Mdo5JMdjI6J1NI3wul7IWH1HnXMcS9ZxGioYozqSMe5SMDEgqthjJ5-yXnmPeZYr5jMflQrhl4hyAsXE2MCZAjZtt9l7X+QrAqvj6iBTViTQya0CLbManrZqhtSYFxNqOLQaR3YhPxXs+2rLHbO1dtSTl6z-TWC9pHMcjgA5BxDmHY6EqtAx3jonQuIhRC+CAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :) I understood both of the approaches properly.

Comment: jcalz: I'm failing to pass the `Item` information to `getInitialValue` and `getDefaultValue` functions. I've asked a new question for it. — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932066/typescript-control-flow-based-types-with-generics