# Typescript: Get More Targeted Return Types of Function Signatures Which Take Generic Parameters

Tags: typescript

I've the following types

```js
interface AutosuggestState<Item> {
  highlightedIndex: number | null
  inputValue: string | null
  isOpen: boolean
  selectedItem: Item | null
}

interface ItemToString<Item> {
  (item: Item): string;
}

interface AutosuggestProps<Item> {
    itemToString?: ItemToString<Item>;

    highlightedIndex?: number | null;
    inputValue?: string | null;
    isOpen?: boolean;
    selectedItem?: Item;

    initial?: {
        highlightedIndex?: number | null;
        inputValue?: string | null;
        isOpen?: boolean;
        selectedItem?: Item;
    }

    default?: {
        highlightedIndex?: number | null;
        inputValue?: string | null;
        isOpen?: boolean;
        selectedItem?: Item;
    }
}
```

This is the code

```js
const defaultStateValues: AutosuggestState<null> = {
  highlightedIndex: -1,
  isOpen: false,
  selectedItem: null,
  inputValue: ''
}

function getDefaultValue<
  I,
  P extends AutosuggestProps<I>,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState<I>
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {
  if (props.default && typeof props.default[statePropKey] !== "undefined") {
    const ret = props.default[statePropKey]
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>;
  }
  return defaultStateValues[statePropKey]
}

function getInitialValue<
  I,
  P extends AutosuggestProps<I>,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState<I>
>(
  props: P,
  statePropKey: K
) {

  if (statePropKey in props && typeof props[statePropKey] !== 'undefined') {
    const ret = props[statePropKey]
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>
  }

  if (props.initial && typeof props.initial[statePropKey] !== 'undefined') {
    const ret = props.initial[statePropKey];
    return ret as Exclude<typeof ret, undefined>
  }

  return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
}

function getInitialState<
  I
>(
  props: AutosuggestProps<I>
): AutosuggestState<I> {

  const selectedItem = getInitialValue(props, 'selectedItem')
  const highlightedIndex = getInitialValue(props, 'highlightedIndex')
  const isOpen = getInitialValue(props, 'isOpen')
  const inputValue = getInitialValue(props, 'inputValue')

  return {
    highlightedIndex,
    isOpen,
    selectedItem,
    inputValue,
  }
}

function useAutosuggest<
  I
>(
  userProps: AutosuggestProps<I>
){
  const initialState = getInitialState( userProps );
}
```

**Problems**:

1. If you open this code on [TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcwHsDO6Dm+EOYAymHJADwCSkAtgHzIDeAUMsgBbD5cA2vLpAAmNECIgAPAFzIQ6egCNoyAD7z0-fh2SgADpgBqcfughySUUPnWbtu4DgDy+iCDlKsWfhDghdHAhfBFE6CHo5cPo7BQcAXzY2UEhYRBRogBUscmsQfFoGZnZOAApgBiiGAEpLMDz8AG42ROTwaHgkNExcAiISAAUoLH0cQoji3U4KiOzcmwB+Ktmc+ptxpmbOKe4hQT4wiWklzWVVDTj+Lc49EEMwEzMIE6sbWK0rnadXdxOvHz8IGunCCITCDBO0WaXxAFWAphOJRuyJ4fH2wggYiOUhOCjOUHe2mByNu90e5hea3yhM+JJu3zcID+3l8-mJyNBEFCmOikIYxNayMk8C0YEROxReyEh0kOLkeJUBIuH3Z9LuxlMFLqDRpqumLkZzIBbIlN053LEEOW9AFLSSCCwIBIyGFcFF5EoEHJxDkGGweEIxDIFGol2YAF5WLpUQJpTzsXIALQARgANI4De45PB+EF0yDglzwRF5R986SNU85AByat2tgwdAgULAR3IIhgAAiEBF-AemogVF0NHLA2Q0kgEhw3X9fSDQxGYxojHLAGlx1JJyJpwBrCAATywMBnvUDJA91GXbEYpV0+mGozkA3LJE9C-0q4PclXbGqUemx6lPei4AHSuqKyAAGSQcgYD7m4R7IMBoxgT2bp9gA2q+kDvp++4ALrIAAhOGkYAERNsKoCYmRf5IpwDpOmAyBQBAzGRshOCob2YBYSGEC4Qe+E7KxYDoFAIAsWxyBwNOACiUgIGYkhUHBCHHqJqbIJRPbUSIjDXIknCieJkngX2F5egOOB8W+D54cJrSNs2YCtpJHbiHCpjekOnAjroY4Tu424ngG-RgO+S4rro65BVOyB7oex5+qe4WWbQjDXrenCcU+L78YJ+7fr+UaOIB2ECfZB63EhD7TtBsHwRAiGcbZOFVQRxGkcg1Y6TAenVnROyMc6onIBxdVtZVIwOSJbGmVJzGycgClKegKlqc1GlsVpfV6ZlnCCnogGcSBoBefwUEwZtLV1WdsKuaYU2FYRJGRr1Rz9SAmKDf+NwjcxY0TaB52Pfwz0dfhxImRJi0yfJinKYON3bWAu2fftuhHTD7lsd2PHekBdVaRVhXVPWzktm2HkPfC-DpcOWV3nVvo9GF851Rlv6s7OZ7Bp6GWlQxjrOuaxYxJGNMXYTnFadWYs8gwg26ADuxonGWKyuN7ZsZ5YMy8TPUxuiMrSMrwtMXomaSZLuu095A5E4ucsMu45vIKrBiVuY2tS-rjuyz1Xv9k8yu6Djf2cMbGviLK5b6j8IDx8gCuWhEyfB965aJE5TZU5J6BBCl7MkL5yA0EznCF9AkU86lHOLlz1RIp79v0-xvt2xdlmlNpQRQJFyDVM08RAA) you'll find that

the `getInitialValue` calls inside `getInitialState` function are complaining, for example for

```js
const highlightedIndex = getInitialValue(props, 'highlightedIndex')
```

`props` complain –

```
Argument of type 'AutosuggestProps<I>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AutosuggestProps<unknown>'.
```

similarly, the `getDefaultValue` call inside `getInitialValue`

```js
return getDefaultValue(props, statePropKey)
```

`props` complain the same thing.

I'm not able to figure out proper types for functions `getInitialValue`, `getDefaultValue` which will incorporate the generic type `I` properly, that is passed from `useAutosuggest`. The control flow based types, I'm not able to write properly.

2. The types are coming incorrect ( in the line below ) for `initialState`, except for `selectedItem`

```js
  const initialState = getInitialState( userProps );

/**
    initialState is of type 

    highlightedIndex: number | null; ✅
    isOpen: boolean; // ✅
    selectedItem: unknown; // should come I | null
    inputValue: string | null; ✅
*/
```

3. how do I limit the `I` generic in `useAutosuggest` function and hence everywhere in the flow of the function call, to a particular constraint ( it could either be an object or a string, nothing else )
4. given the code, am I wrongly typing something, or not doing something properly? Could something be typed better to make this code better?

Comment: It seems like you're asking multiple distinct questions, and the code shown isn't necessarily a minimal example for each. For (1) I'd manually specify generics like `getInitialValue<I, typeof props, "selectedItem">(props, 'selectedItem')` everywhere the compiler can't infer them. That will solve (2). For (3) I'd say `<I extends object | string>` everywhere you are currently defining `I`. For (4), I'd say there's no good inference site for `I` anywhere in your calls and things seem possibly too generic; you might not need `P`. But this question is so wide in scope I'm not comfortable answering.

Comment: I'm finding it really difficult to ask what I want to in a proper independently compartmentalised way. What I really need is for someone to show me how would one write types for this piece of code I'm trying to write types of, and there's no one around I could take help of. But I can't generally ask questions like that on stackoverflow. Hence the conundrum. I'll try to frame the question(s) properly and ask again. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

set default type like this:

```
function getDefaultValue<
  I = any,
  P extends AutosuggestProps<I> = AutosuggestProps<I>,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState<I> = keyof AutosuggestState<I>
>(

function getInitialValue<
  I = any,
  P extends AutosuggestProps<I> = AutosuggestProps<I>,
  K extends keyof AutosuggestState<I> = keyof AutosuggestState<I>
>(
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=61&ssc=3&pln=57&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcwHsDO6Dm%20EOYAymHJADwCSkAtgHzIDeAUMsgBbD5cA2vLpAAmNECIgAPAFzIQ6egCNoyAD7z0-fh2SgADpgBqcfughySUUPnWbtu4DgDy%20iCDlKsWfhDghdHAhfBFE6CHo5cPo7BQcAXzY2UEhYRBRogBUscmsQfFoGZnZOAApgBiiGAEpLMDz8AG42ROTwaHgkNExcAiISAAUoLH0cQoji3U4KiOzcmwB%20Ktmc%20ptxpmbOKe4hQT4wiWklzWVVDTj%20Lc49EEMwEzMIE6sbWK0rnadXdxOvHz8IGunCCITCDBO0WaXxAFWAphOJRuyJ4fH2wggYiOUhOCjOUHe2mByNu90e5hea3yhM%20JJu3zcID%203l8-mJyNBEFCmOikIYxNayMk8C0YEROxReyEh0kOLkeJUBIuH3Z9LuxlMFLqDRpqumLkZzIBbIlN053LEEOW9AFLSSCCwIBIyGFcFF5EoEHJxDkGGweEIxDIFGol2YAF5WLpUQJpTzsXIALQARgANI4De45PB%20EF0yDglzwRF5R986SNU85AByat2tgwdAgULAR3IIhgAAiEBF-AemogVF0NGQkf8AE9ywNkNJIBIcN1-X0g0MRmMaBHF71A4NhqNaIxywBpGdSOciBcAawg46wMC3Af6wc9B9HyGvt-vfu3T491A3bCMKUuj6HuOByAM5YkJ6q76EeN5yEebDVFG0z3qUoFrgAdK6orIAAZPhyBgOObh3sgmGjDhPZun2ADa0GQLB8HjgAusgACE4aRgARE2wqgJiPEoUinAOk6YDIFAECSZGlE4NRvZgAxIYQMxN6sTs0lgOgUAgFJMnIHAC4AKJSAgZiSFQJFkfe2mpsg-E9oJIiMNciScNpun6bhfZ-l6A44CpMF7ixmmtI2zZgK2%20kduIcKmN6Q6cCOY4gJOujTrO7gXg%20y67mur6Rt%20j4rmBB7Hqe55Xje5Elflz7-puH51T0pUkP5B6AcBnDyRBUGqep46IchUaOOhjFqaFN63BRYEEURNkQOR8nBUx01sZx3HINWTkwC51YiTs4nOtpb6rZNQ2aciXl6QZknGcgZkWegVlLeR9mOUc%200gJijC6IKejofJWGgAl-ALcRpHLfeINg9FphrVNIxhVtka7d9B1HciJ2SWdclgaDsII-wSNXcSt36Wdj3PZZg7vXZMkOXtLn-ZwgOU%202Mndkp3oYWBDmXRt1T1pFLZtnFxPwvwnXDt1IFgb6bUNbB67-bUeU7o1g4bmNYmOs65rFjEkaS%20DfPyQ51ZGzyDCHbouO7GicZYrKb5myTFsCztMbojK0j2-rEl6Jm%20mmzJ8WewO-NrlbDLuIHyCOwYlbmO7EdS4l0eWztKf9k89u6JzolO7GBzxrK5b6j8IBV8gNuWhEdd5965aJBFTbi-p6BBPVWvJcgNDy5wPfQKrStLlrqtddUSLJ5nMuqenYCR9L-mlI5QRQKryDVM08RAA)

Comment: How do I constraint `I` to be a particular type only? I want it to be either an object or a string? Can you extend your answer with that?

Comment: I added the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways and found the way I think the best.
You can't set the `Item` to `object | string` before because of the `itemToString` in `AutosuggestProps`. The function parameters need meet [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types). When the `Item` has been set to `object | string`, It against this rule. So I tried this [palyground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=11&pln=12&pc=27#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcwHsDO6Dm+EOYAymHJMgN4BQyyAFsPowDYuOQAmAkiNwgAPAFzIQ6ALYAjaMgA+49Gzb1koAA6YAanDboIYklFD4FSlWuA4A8hoggx0rFjYQ4INTghuEPXpCSRmAmIGaKWNIAVhB+5hKWAL60tKCQsIgoARCSACpY5KFmdAwAFMCBwUXmkTF+AJRVpgDctMmp4NDwSGiYuAREJAAKUFgaODRqDBU5+YWmAPxi2XkFIS1qU0ycHKz+AsJLSjJyiglsrQzTIFpguvoQR8am8coXW9Z2DkfOru4glyu3l8-kCT3WYRq0ViYFaHxAFWAeiOJSuaOYrF2XAgfAOQiOEhOUFeKkBaOut3uBnB1TObzJ5M+9hAPxcbg8DLRwJhOJWNJeEWhfgZ7TRgngyjAKK26J2nH2gnxYkJsmJdNJMqumh0empTUh6ve5K1tmZrL+HM1DG5fl5YP14WQtRhIraKQQWBAJGQ4rgkvIlAgVOIYgw2DwhGIZAoVAAvJMGBj2PLeXixABaACMABorKaHGJ4GxvLnrT4eXxKhY2KX1DcdQ8xAByJtu2gwdAgPzAT3IIhgAAiEAlbDuuogAB41ENkMJIAIJmH+pHhqNxrWANKzoTz7gTADWEAAnlgYL1wwMowHILQAHylNQaNc4MRDWskQMjMYb49iDe0eoE3UM9SifMYcAAOl9SVkAAMlg5AwCPexT2QMDxig4c-VHABtD9IC-DQfyPABdZAAEJY3jAAiTtxVAHFqMA1EGA9L0wGQKAIA4+N0Mg6DcPwiBCOIkiti4sB0CgEBOO45A4AmABRIQEH0QQJyQlCzwk7NkDo4cGO4W9AWSBgJKkmSBOjQNgxwPCY2EtdRLbDsuzAHsZP7fhET0YMpwYGc5wcPdz2XQYwEInBN23XcD2PVClwjcLrwgO8HwYPjX3fByRN-ZB-2YlJphAoTcqPOs0OfOCEM0iBUL4+zPyc48yMo+Mm30mBDKbQq0TY70JOQXjn0agjmtI8TuIs2SOIU5BlNU9B1Nq1CdL0g4upAHFbzUUVgOQUDnwg0AfLYarEOQuqzz446EXcvRRsc78WooqjkA6jbut6q5+o4wbhvA27TsesqSIZczpJm+SlJUtTJxW7TuN0zrDJ2hg9ohzzuKHEcxweQ7wN00rxvqFzO27XsvLupE2BS9LKvA0M+iSqNIoApmLxXayqDoNRfuQG1QRyIa+247z7rYYMCfXd7BbtHIer5z1vSTLEFWEEWqdOqW+N0ptVZTXFFUV1jlY4pkHE1sXqd88dpai96LZAE3kH57U8YMK2wHFmmdefPX3eDRW1ExoDEzlPZU0VWtpnzEAY4F8tbUrHIE8D8da2SdpXIpmT0G8RLLxIen8+gSKObC1nnwA1E3Zt2mHK9n29DpvTvCgSLkHqVpEiAA)

Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you for answering again :) The reason I was taking a generic for the type of `selectedItem` was because, many other things inside my function `useAutosuggest` are dependent on it, including `itemToString` function. I want the user of my `useAutosuggest` function to pass the type of `selectedItem` and get correct autosuggestions with a code editor like vscode for all the things that it would return. Is there a way the code could be written with `selectedItem`'s type generic included like originally intended? We can leave the item to not be `object | string` for the reason you gave.